# Changing Bar chart color based on value

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have the following data:
8,518,000
27,525,000
20,532,000
12,897,000
(27,858,000)
(5,266,000)
(18,442,000)
(78,850,000)
(43,813,000)
(26,920,000)
(4,501,000)
(19,619,000)
(12,938,000)
The first four years positive and the last 9 years is negative.

For my plotly barchart, I want the color to be black when positive and red when negative. What is the easiest way to color this?

Right now I have everything set to red with marker_color='red' but marker_color[0:3]='black' causes an error.

Comment: Your question is very vague and hard to understand. For example: how exactly are those years. Try explaining your doubt by giving some example.

Comment: Can you provide more code to clarify what you want? Also is this data tuples or numbers with thousands separators?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but if I understand you correctly, you can make a list of colors for each data point, then pass a dictionary of this colors list to the `marker` parameter.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y = [8510000, 27525000, 20532000, 12897000, 
27858000, 5266000, 18442000, 78850000, 43813000, 26920000, 4501000, 19619000, 12938000]
# colors list with first 4 set to 'black', last 9 set to 'red'
colors = ['black']*4 + ['red']*9

data = [dict(type='bar',
    y=y,
    marker=dict(color=colors)
)]

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

[image]